# How to Implement CSRF Guard in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, security, csrf, owasp

I need to implement CSRF(Cross Site Request Forgery) Guard in my code (asp.net).
Though I got a library from OWASP, implementing it is a pain since no documentation is given. Can someone provide me an easier way to implement csrf guard in .net, or configure OWASP library correctly ?

Thanks

-Chandan

Comment: Have you explored the possibility of using native ASP.NET CSRF protection? You can use ViewStateUserKey to prevent CSRF attacks if your app is NOT processing input via querystrings. For HTTP POST requests, ViewStateUserKey protection works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

**ASP.NET MVC**

If you're using asp.net mvc you can use the anti-forgery token.  Basically in your view you would place the following code:

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

And on your controller you would put this attribute at the top of the controller:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
   // Foo code
}
```

What this does is ensures that the user cannot submit the form from a remote site, because they are unable to generate the token.  You can also create a token with a salt.

**ASP.NET WebForms**

For asp.net Webforms you can override the OnInit method and set the ViewStateUserKey to the the session id.  Web forms will validate the viewstate with a MAC check thereby acting like an anti forgery token.  Because an attacker cannot generate a valid viewstate (since they don't have the ability to generate a valid MAC because they can't put the session id in the viewstate) the MAC will fail.  You will have to do this on each page, or create a base class that already overrides oninit and does this.

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        this.ViewStateUserKey = Session.SessionID;
    }
}
```

Comment: and if I'm not using MVC, how do I prevent CSRF?

Comment: @user1663380  I have updated the code to include a webforms example.

Comment: It seems as though the original quest was how to implement CSRFGuard  (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/CSRFGuard_3_User_Manual)  specifically in an ASP.Net implementation.  You have offered a couple of suggestions regarding how to protect against CSRF attacks in .Net, but did not address at all the original question of implementing CSRFGuard in .Net. Here is a link to the GitHub page with the CSRF code (https://github.com/aramrami/OWASP-CSRFGuard).   Does anyone else have any helpful advice on how to implement CSRFGuard in .Net?  Thank you.